# Firebase admin sdk java performance issue

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm having slow performance issues with Firebase realtime database while adding the data.
Firebase app here is the singleton object. I'm using the above to save data in the Firebase  where I'm facing the performance issue. The first request is taking around 14 seconds to save. The following immediate requests are taking milliseconds. Am I experiencing a cold start here? Can someone help me out?  I'm new to Firebase.

```
    @Bean
    public FirebaseApp firebaseApp() {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount;
        try {
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("nextlearningplatform-firebase-adminsdk-1o5of-09005f0e08.json");
            File file = resource.getFile();
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file);
            FirebaseOptions  options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setProjectId("nextlearningplatform")
                    .setStorageBucket("nextlearningplatform.appspot.com")
                    .build();
             FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
             return app;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
 String url = "databaseName";
 String refpath = "referencePath";
 DatabaseReference ref = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp,"https://"+url+".firebaseio.com)
.getReference(refpath);
 ref.child("streams").setValueAsync(firebaseDTO);
```

Comment: It' s possibly a cold start problem. We've experienced poor startup performance (10 to 20s) with a web service using FireStore (FireStore native) as well. We have now migrated from Java to node.js and the startup is about 3s. It would be great to understand what is causing this delay. I didn't look as if our service was busy; rather it was waiting for a cloud service.

Comment: Install a profiler tool (like the JProfiler, but a free sampling profiler is ok too) to inspect where you loose time the most.

Comment: How are you accessing RTDB without setting database URL in `FirebaseOptions`? Did you remove some lines of code when posting the question?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Updated the code.Could have added in the FirebaseOptions itself if it was one dbUrl. My aim is to add the data to all the sharded databases.

Comment: The above code (something very similar to it) takes 2-3 seconds in my machine. Can you repro these long execution times locally? If not profiling in the affected environment is your best option.